# How many separate flash movies can be rendered on one HTML page before performance is noticebly smaller

Tags: apache-flex, flash, memory, browser, portlet

I'm currently developing a portal application that will require a number of Adobe flex elements. Each portlet could potentially be it's own flash movie. What I would like to know is how many of these portlets can be rendered in a browser on an average system before the number flash player starts using up too much memory and performance starts to degrade.

Any kind of documentation on how Flash handles memory in this regard would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

If the flash apps are doing a lot, then they'll take more more cpu and memory.  If each is not doing much, or in a waiting state, then they won't take up more cpu.  This is the same if you have one embedded swf or many swfs, it depends on what they're doing.

Comment: +1 — It's not about how many SWFs are on the page, it's about how much they're doing, what kind of resources they use, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that it greatly depends on what your doing. I guess the answer I'm looking for is, in general, are the number of flash movies on the page something I have to worry a lot about?

Comment: @Codeflayer, no, if you got a bunch of swfs all doing nothing, no worries.